# Jq strange behavior of pipe involving variable on the left hand side

Tags: variables, jq

I came across a weird behavior of `jq` involving a variable on the left hand side of a pipe.

For your information, this question was inspired by the `jq` manual: under `Scoping` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures) where it mentions an example filter `... | .*3 as $times_three | [. + $times_three] | ...`. I believe the correct version is `... | (.*3) as $times_three | [. + $times_three] | ...`.

First (https://jqplay.org/s/ffMPsqmsmt)

```
filter:
. * 3 as $times_three | .
input:
3
output:
9
```

Second (https://jqplay.org/s/yOFcjRAMLL)

```
filter:
. * 4 as $times_four | .
input:
3
output:
9
```

What is happening here?

But (https://jqplay.org/s/IKrTNZjKI8)

```
filter:
(. * 3) as $times_three | .
input:
3
output:
3
```

And (https://jqplay.org/s/8zoq2-HN1G)

```
filter:
(. * 4) as $times_four | .
input:
3
output:
3
```

So if parenthesis `(.*3)` or `(.*4)` is used when the variable is declared then filter behaves predictably.

But if parenthesis is not used `.*3` or `.*4` then strangely the output is 9 for both.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the examples in the *Scoping* section assume, `. * 4 as $times_four | .`  is equivalent to `. * ( 4 as $times_four | . )` and therefore squares its input.

---

You might expect

```
. * 4 as $times_four | .
```

to be equivalent to

```
( . * 4 ) as $times_four | .
```

And as you point out, some example even suggest this is the case. However, the first snippet is actually equivalent to the following:

```
. * ( 4 as $times_four | . )
```

And since `… as $x` produces its context<sup>[1]</sup>, that's the same as

```
. * ( . | . )
```

or

```
. * .
```

`jq`'s operator precedence is inconsistent and/or quirky.

`"def" | "abc"  + "def" | length` means
`"def" | ( "abc" + "def" ) | length`, but
`"def" | "abc"  + "def" as $x | length` means
`"def" | "abc" + ( "def" as $x | length )`.

This behaviour suggests that that `as` isn't a binary operator of the form `X as $Y` as one might expect, but a ternary operator of the form `X as $Y | Z`.

And, in fact, this is how it's documented:

> Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator: `... as $identifier | ...`

This leads to surprises, especially since it binds a lot more tightly than expected. And it looks like whomever authored the examples in the *Scoping* section fell into the trap.

---

1. It might produce it multiple times e.g. `.[] as $x`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there seems to be a mistake in the manual. In section [Scoping](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Scoping) it is contrasting the (faulty) examples

```
... | .*3 as $times_three | [. + $times_three] | ...         # faulty!
```

and

```
... | (.*3 as $times_three | [. + $times_three]) | ...       # faulty!
```

While the overall statement stays valid, both examples are missing **additional** parentheses around `.*3`. Thus, it should actually read

```
... | (.*3) as $times_three | [. + $times_three] | ...
```

and

```
... | ((.*3) as $times_three | [. + $times_three]) | ...
```

respectively.

---

From the manual under section [Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable%2FSymbolicBindingOperator%3A...as%24identifier%7C...):

> The expression `exp as $x | ...` means: for each value of expression `exp`, run the rest of the pipeline with the entire original input, and with `$x` set to that value. Thus `as` functions as something of a foreach loop.

This means that a variable assignment takes the **one** expression left of `as` and assigns its evaluation to the defined variable right of `as` (and this happens as many times as `exp` produces an output). But, as everything in jq is a filter, the assignment itself also is, and as such it needs to have an output itself. If you look closely, the full title of that section

> Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator: `... as $identifier | ...`

also features a pipe symbol next to it, which indicates that it belongs to the assignment's structure. Try just running `. as $x`. You will get an error because the `| ...` part is missing. Thus, to simply keep the input context as is (apart from maybe duplicating it as many times as the expression left of `as` produced an output), a complete assignment would rather look like `… as $x | .`, or, if the input context is what you wanted to capture in the variable, `. as $x | .`

That said, let's clarify what happens with your examples by putting explicit parentheses around the assignments:

```
3 | . * 3 as $times_three | .
3 | . * (3 as $times_three | .)
3 | . * .                           # with $times_three set to 3
3 * 3                               # with $times_three set to 3
9                                   # with $times_three set to 3
```

```
3 | . * 4 as $times_four | .
3 | . * (4 as $times_four | .)
3 | . * .                           # with $times_four set to 4
3 * 3                               # with $times_four set to 4
9                                   # with $times_four set to 4
```

```
3 | (. * 3) as $times_three | .
3 | ((. * 3) as $times_three | .)
3 | ((3 * 3) as $times_three | .)
3 | (9 as $times_three | .)
3 | .                               # with $times_three set to 9
3                                   # with $times_three set to 9
```

```
3 | (. * 4) as $times_four | .
3 | ((. * 4) as $times_four | .)
3 | ((3 * 4) as $times_four | .)
3 | (12 as $times_four | .)
3 | .                               # with $times_four set to 12
3                                   # with $times_four set to 12
```